# Connecting to AWS RDS PostgreSQL Database Failed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-rds, node-postgres

I am new to AWS and backend development. I failed to connect an AWS online database using node-postgres with the code below.

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
  host: 'database-1.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '<master-password>',
  database: 'postgres'
});
```

The error message I got was `connect ECONNREFUSED`, and I am not sure what each parameter (`host`, `port`, `user`, `password`, `database`) for initializing the client object corresponds to. By the way, here is some information I retrieved in the cloudshell.

```sh
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-82-165 ~]$ aws rds describe-db-instances \
>   --query "*[].[DBInstanceIdentifier,Endpoint.Address,Endpoint.Port,MasterUsername]"
[
    [
        "database-1",
        "database-1.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        5432,
        "postgres"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Most likely the RDS instance is not visible to the internet or to the service you are using (i.e. EC2). Make sure you added correct subnet groupt, security group(s) and if you want to have it publicly accessible to also choose publicly accessible.

Comment: FWIW, your parameters are correct for your RDS instance. Try seeing if you can hit your DB server on that port from whatever system you are doing your node.js work on. Like `telnet database-1.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432` or `nc -z database-1.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432` or `cat /dev/tcp/database-1.*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/5432` or what-have-you. If it isn't then @libik suggestions are spot-on for next steps to open the line between the two systems.